# Given two shapes, work out how to completely cover one with copies of the other

Tags: geometry

This question is really about surveying an area - how many photos must I take to cover the survey area?

I have a square with sides of 100m. I also have another square, with sides of 30m.

I wish to cover the 100m-sided square completely, using copies of the 30m square. How do I determine the placement of the 30m squares so that the minimum amount of 30m squares is used? The squares can overlap, and are allowed to extend out of the 100m square.

Changes to the tags are welcome, if geometry doesn't fit.

Comment: This is an example of a covering problem, which are usually very hard. Here are the [best known results for the squares covering squares problem](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squcosqu/); for your example, it is possible to do it with 15 squares.

Comment: A related and interesting problem worth reading about is the [Art gallery problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem).  It is different than what you describe as you seem to be limiting yourself for each occurrence of surveying to be doing so using 30m squares, whereas in the art gallery problem so long as the guards have line of sight with their target they don't care about distance.

Comment: @Rahul why not post this as an answer?